# interesting t-sql exercise

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to resolve t-sql exercise
I need to update first table with values from second by joining by id. If I can not join then use value from default ID (default iD is the Id that is null)

please run it to see it

```
declare @t as table (
    [id] INT
    ,val int
)

insert into @t values (null, null)
insert into @t values (2, null)
insert into @t values (3, null)
insert into @t values (4, null)

declare @t2 as table (
    [id] INT
    ,val int
)

insert into @t2 values (null, 11)
insert into @t2 values (2, 22)
insert into @t2 values (3, 33)


select * from @t
select * from @t2

update t
set t.val = t2.val
from @t as t join @t2 as t2
    on t.id = t2.id
        or 
        (
            (t.id is null or t.id not in (select id from @t2))
            and t2.id is null
        )




select * from @t
```

here is result

```
--@t
id      val
---------------
NULL    NULL
2       NULL
3       NULL
4       NULL

--@t2
id      val
---------------
NULL    11
2       22
3       33

--@t after update
id      val
---------------
NULL    11
2       22
3       33
4       NULL
```

how to make val in last row equal 11?

```
4       11
```

Comment: are you saying the default `val` is in the row with a null `id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this for the update...

```
update t
set t.val = t2.val
from @t as t join @t2 as t2
    on t.id = t2.id
        or 
        (
            (t.id is null or not exists (select * from @t2 where id = t.id))
            and t2.id is null
        )
```

Problem is with `not in` operator and `null` values. This would also work...

```
update t
set t.val = t2.val
from @t as t join @t2 as t2
    on t.id = t2.id
        or 
        (
            (t.id is null or t.id not in (select id from @t2 where id is not null))
            and t2.id is null
        )
```

Comment: I like your solutions better than mine as they don't require the LEFT JOINS or the coalesce. I'm really surprised the `and t2.id is null` worked in the context of an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: lol, honestly, if I was writing the query, I'd just pull the default into a variable or do the extra outer join. Me not likey joining on nulls!

Answer (score 3):

This solution left joins to t2 twice and then does a coalesce.

The `ON` on the second join matches on records that failed on the join and then looks for the "Default" case.

```
UPDATE t
set t.val = COALESCE(t2.val,t3.val)
from @t as t 
    LEFT join @t2 as t2
    on t.id = t2.id
    LEFT JOIN @t2 t3 
    ON t2.id is null and t3.id is null
```

[See it working here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66958/sample-for-10181882)

Comment: Thank you for a great sample.  Double left join for the same table is something I need to dig in more.  I picked dotjoe's version because it shows how to resolve issue in my cod

Answer (score 1):

Here's a technique that may help.

Start with the kind of simple code you want to be writing:

```
MERGE INTO @t AS target 
   USING source 
      ON target.id = source.id 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET val = source.val;
```

Then write a table expression (`source`) that satisfies the requirements.

Requirement 1: "joining by id"

-- simple existential quantification e.g.

```
SELECT id, val
  FROM @t2 AS T2
 WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM @t )
```

Requirement 2: "If I can not join then use value from default ID (default iD is the Id that is null)"

-- first find the `id` values in the target that do not exist in the source:

```
SELECT id
  FROM @t
EXCEPT
SELECT id
  FROM @t2
```

then cross join the result with the row from the source where Id is null:

```
SELECT DT1.id, T2.val
  FROM ( SELECT id
          FROM @t
         EXCEPT
         SELECT id
          FROM @t2 ) AS DT1, 
       @t2 AS T2 
 WHERE T2.id IS NULL
```

At this point you will want to query some test data to ensure each query satisfies its respective requirement.

Union the above two results to form a single table expression:

```
SELECT id, val
  FROM @t2 AS T2
 WHERE id IN ( SELECT id
                 FROM @t )             
UNION
SELECT DT1.id, T2.val
  FROM ( SELECT id
          FROM @t
         EXCEPT
         SELECT id
          FROM @t2 ) AS DT1, 
       @t2 AS T2 
 WHERE T2.id IS NULL
```

Then plug the table expression into the `MERGE` boilerplate code:

```
WITH source
     AS
     (
      SELECT id, val
        FROM @t2 AS T2
       WHERE id IN ( SELECT id
                       FROM @t )             
      UNION
      SELECT DT1.id, T2.val
        FROM ( SELECT id
                FROM @t
               EXCEPT
               SELECT id
                FROM @t2 ) AS DT1, 
             @t2 AS T2 
       WHERE T2.id IS NULL
     )
MERGE INTO @t AS target 
   USING source 
      ON target.id = source.id 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET val = source.val;
```